# How to load Spring Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I Have a Spring project. It works fine with junit test case. juint calls the applicationcontext.xml and the project run successfully. But i want to run the project without using jUnit.
Here is my jUnit Test Case

```
package com.dataload;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:com/dataload/applicationcontext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class SICSVDataTestCase {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(SICSVDataTestCase.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher launcher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    private JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();

    @Test
    public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
        sw.stop();
        logger.info(">>> TIME ELAPSED:" + sw.prettyPrint());
    }
}
```

This testcase run the project. But i want to use another class that can call the applicationcontext.xml and run the project.

That is,

```
package com.dataload;

public class insertCSV 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /*  Code to run the project */
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to code? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this at the start of main

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/applicationContext.xml");

JobLauncher launcher=(JobLauncher)context.getBean("launcher");
Job job=(Job)context.getBean("job");

//Get as many beans you want
//Now do the thing you were doing inside test method
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.start();
launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
sw.stop();
//initialize the log same way inside main
logger.info(">>> TIME ELAPSED:" + sw.prettyPrint());
```

Comment: Thanks. Its Loading. But When i run the test case i didn't need to call  all methods in other class. It was executing automatically. But here It loads the applicationcontext.xml only. Why that happens?

Comment: If your applicationContext has all the beans to be initialized then this will work fine. If you want to call other stuffs you have to manually do that once application context is loaded. How do you want your main class to behave??

Comment: But in testcase it was executing all methods without calling.

Comment: Thats because you had only single test method dude :)

Comment: if you run the junit as a whole all methods annotated with `@Test` will execute. You can run specific test methods as well. But in main you have to call methods that you need to run.

Comment: ok. Thankyou!
Do i need to download any jar for ApplicationContextUtil?

Answer (score 1):

I am using in the way and it is working for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CarpoolDBAppTest();

}

public CarpoolDBAppTest(){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    Student stud = (Student) context.getBean("yourBeanId");
}
```

Here Student is my classm you will get the class matching yourBeanId.

Now work on that object with whatever operation you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.dataload;

    public class insertCSV 
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ApplicationContext context =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");


            // retrieve configured instance
            JobLauncher launcher = context.getBean("laucher", JobLauncher.class);
            Job job = context.getBean("job", Job.class);
            JobParameters jobParameters = context.getBean("jobParameters", JobParameters.class);
        }
    }
```